# Why are accepted answers included in the review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, accepted-answer

I was recently looking at the Late Answers and First Answers review queues and something like three review tasks in a row were for accepted answers.

Why are accepted answers included in review queues and not automatically removed? It seems like most accepted answers, on average, tend to be higher quality and include sufficient explanations/correct formatting. In other words, most of the time, if an answer is accepted it doesn't include any major problems that would be flagged in review queues. For example, I don't think I have ever clicked something other than Looks Fine on an accepted answer.

Furthermore, if an answer was accepted it is likely high enough quality that it was useful to the original person asking the question. Within a context of enormous review queue backlogs and limited volunteer support, it seems like a waste of time/resources to include accepted answers in the review queues. Is there a reason for this?

The only thing I can think of is that this protects against new users answering and accepting their own answers of lower quality. My argument would be that even if this is the case, they are still likely providing information that is useful for answering the original question.

Interested to hear people's thoughts or an explanation for this.

Comment: Does this happen often? My experience with spam is that is is almost always immediately downvoted and removed from the site within 5 minutes. (Actions taken outside of the review queues)

Comment: You just answered your own question with "almost always". For everything else, review queues are a second line of defense

Comment: Just because someone accepts and answer does not mean that it meets our site's standards. Counterquestion: Why should a 1-rep user (with little to no understanding of how the site works) be able to unilaterally stop a post from being assessed for quality?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Interesting point, thank you.

Comment: @HenryEcker This makes sense.

Comment: Not sure why asking a clarifying question gets so many downvotes, I did not see the duplicate when I was searching for an answer lol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes spammers create [spam seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed) posts. These are relatively innocuous, often a plagiarised repeat of a useful question. We don't always catch these questions as spam because they are potentially genuine.

Then they self answer or their sock puppet does and they can then accept that answer. If that acceptance removes one of our defences against spam that doesn't seem like a good thing to do.

In fact acceptance is not a great signal that we have a good question or a good answer because the question asker is unlikely to be the best judge of question quality. They are usually asking the question because they don't know the subject area very well. Obviously there are exceptions where a subject matter expert will ask and self answer to help everyone but such questions are uncommon.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I guess I was oversimplifying the quality assessment portion of the answers. Thank you for this detailed explanation.

Comment: What is a "seed post"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As explained in the rest of the answer I.e innocuous looking posts that spammers can use to add spam answers to, or edit into spam later.